# How Grant Select access to view in schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Need to Grant an access to only the view of XYZ schema, View internally call the Table from dbo Schema. need to restrict access to dbo table.
as i am only giving access to XYZ schema when i try to slect XYZ.VIEW. it gives and error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 2
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Table1', database 'servername', schema 'dbo'.
```

Query to Grant access to user

```
GRANT SELECT ON XYZ.VIEW TO user1
```

XYZ.VIEW Definition is below

```
SELECT NAME, Adress
FROM  dbo.Table1
```

Comment: you need to grant the view and the tables in the view

Comment: I don't want to give access to the table, as user can query which the column which is don't want to show him. by view i am trying to restrict the columns user can see.

Comment: Grant select on only the columns needed?

Comment: you are only giving them access to the view which has a limited number of columns. if you don't give them the actual tables then i don't see it as a problem.

Comment: My view is having Column only Name column
SELECT NAME
FROM  XYZ.View

and my table have SELECT NAME, Adress
FROM  dbo.Table1  and if i give access to table he can query name and address .

Comment: Is worth granting access to the table, and then looking at dynamic data masking.  You can effectively mask the additional columns. Has been available since 2016 - there’s a good tutorial on plural site if you take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user to access the table and all of its contents and only access what you have in view, then create a Materialized view. This will isolate the user to what you give them and will remove the need to give them access to the table.